# How to find and read an output from get_referrers an why its lenght is different from getrefcount in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I'm trying to debug my software and find every reference to an object, so I can fully delete it .

So when I did:

```py
    gc.collect()
    print('it has '+str(sys.getrefcount(my_obj))+' references')
    refs = gc.get_referrers(my_obj)
    for r in refs:
        print('ref: '+str(r))
```

output is:

```
it has 5 references
ref: <cell at 0x109758c40: ViAdd object at 0x109758a90>
```

- Why it said 5 references, but only returned one?
- How to inspect what is "cell" address? How to find it in my code? How to debug it, so i can find place in my code that creates it?

I'm using weakref when creating parent-children hierarchy and lambda function for callback, so i do not need to bind object methods